# MS Access Error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set

Tags: ms-access, vba

Error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set is thrown when I run this code:

```
Private Sub Cmdsave_Click()
    Dim db As database
    For i = 0 To LISTQTY.ListCount - 1 Step 1
        db.Execute "Updatable tblstock set boxQty = boxQty + " & LISTQTY.Column(1, i) & "  where PID=" & Me.LISTQTY.Column(0, i) & ""
        'CurrentDb.Updatable
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: No capitalization in the title, no content, unformatted code.  I can't even give you an E for effort.  You should read  [how to ask}.  In the future please put forth some effort.  Honestly, I shouldn't have edited your post or posted an answer.

Comment: `Updatable` rather than `Update`?

Answer (score 0):

The database variable is not set.

```
Private Sub Cmdsave_Click()
    Dim db As database
    Set db = CurrentDb
    For i = 0 To LISTQTY.ListCount - 1 Step 1
        db.Execute "Updatable tblstock set boxQty = boxQty + " & LISTQTY.Column(1, i) & "  where PID=" & Me.LISTQTY.Column(0, i) & ""
    Next
End Sub
```

Or just use the `CurrentDb`

> ```
> CurrentDb..Execute "Updatable tblstock set boxQty = boxQty + " & LISTQTY.Column(1, i) & "  where PID=" & Me.LISTQTY.Column(0, i) & ""
> ```